# Communication between Raspberry Pi3 and iPhone/Android via Bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, android

I have installed Bluez5 and Pluseaudio 5 in raspberry Pi3 and Now I am able to connect to iphone and Mac using command line tool "bluetoothctl" in raspberry Pi. 
In bluetoothctl I have to type the commands to connect to a device.

But I want other way around. A python code in raspberry Pi which can communicate with iPhone app over bluetooth. 
It's like raspberry Pi keep listening like a server and when I connect to raspberry pi from iPhone It should then get connected. 
Simply I want to control a LED or servo motor connected to Pi from iphone over bluetooth.

Can somebody help me with this ?

I am using Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Does it have to be Bluetooth? I believe there are tutorials for running a webserver on the Pi, setting up a WiFi hotspot and then having your iPhone just connect to the Pi's web-server and issuing commands (using buttons on a webpage).

Comment: I did this with android/raspberry pi 3 [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrhyZieHFOg "youtube demo")

Comment: I too would like to see a tutorial on this. Android works great. Can't get my iPhone to find a raspberry pi 3 to send serial data too. I've used blue term and it won't find it. I believe it has something to do with Bluetooth LE not being fully supported